# Problem with api after deploying and setting environment variables?

Tags: python, api, heroku, environment-variables

I wanted to deploy my web app to github, but before doing that I changed the values of the variables in .env file to some garbage value. After changing them and running the application I'm still able to connect to the api even thought I put some garbage value in .env variables. This wasn't happening before when I was directly providing the values those variables, it started to happen after I created the .env file and deployed the app on heroku. How to fix this?

Edit: I'm talking about running the application locally.

```
spotify_client_id = os.getenv('CLIENT_ID')
spotify_client_secret = os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET')

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(
          auth_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=spotify_client_id, client_secret=spotify_client_secret))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. Pycharm was creating a .cache file and saving the access token in it and using that to call api. Deleting that file fixed the problem.